# How to check the toggled-hidden state with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

When my ajax-call is (non-)successfull, I toggle the hidden state from  one of my three alert-div's.

```
$('#alert-success).toggle(':hidden');
```

When, after a first save, I make some more changes and save again I want the #alert-success to be reset to normal state (hidden) so it will appear again after a successfull ajax-call.

What happens now is that my #alert-success just disappears when submitting because of the .toggle(':hidden').

How can I do a reset? I tried this without success:

```
function resetAlerts() {
    $(document).each(function() {
        if ($('.alert').not(':hidden')) {
            $('.alert').toggle(':hidden');
        }
    })
}
```

So I was thinking that this .not(':hidden') only works on values loaded in the DOM and not changed afterwards. Can it be?

Comment: `function resetAlerts(){ $('.alert').hide(); }`

Comment: @blex and it can be so simple. I am breaking my head over the past 2 hours cause I was focusing on that hidden-attribute. Should I also use .show() instead of .toggle('hidden')?

Comment: Haha, I haven't seen your whole code, but theorically, that would work (and be way simpler). `toggle()` is just a way of alternating between different states (hidden or visible) without having to keep track of them. If you just want to show them or hide them at some point, `show()` and `hide()` are appropriate to use.

Answer (score 1):

you can check if your element  `.is(':visible')` and then add/remove the class `hidden` , and in your css have: `.hidden {display:none;}`

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the documentation page, [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-setShown), if you want to toggle it you can just use `.toggle();` without any parameter like below:

```js
$( "button" ).click(function() {
    $( "p" ).toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Toggle</button>
<p>Hello</p>
<p style="display: none">Good Bye</p>
```